# Facebook sends a blank signed request when secure browsing is enabled

Tags: php

I just want to ask a question about Facebook "signed_request" thing. Its return null value when secure browsing is enabled in facebook user account.
I used this code...`

```
    <?php
    // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $applicationID,
      'secret' => $applicationSecret,
    ));

    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

    $page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
    $like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];

    if ($like_status) 
    {
    echo "You like us";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "You not like us";
    }


?>
```

thanks...

Answer (score 2):

A first step is to print data recived from facebook:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

When secure browsing is enabled in facebook user account, facebook will try to load your application from https (you must set this in app settings). Is your app hosted on a https location too ?